# Visual Studio 2017 Build Solution fails

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

`Build Solution` fails in VS 2017:

Have tried the following:

1. Rebuilt project
2. Reinstalled Nuget package
3. Reinstalled VS 2017

Still hitting the same error.

```
The "GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask" task was not found. Check the following: 
1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 
2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 
3.) The task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin" directory.
```

Comment: Have you also checked the three things it mentions in the error message?

Comment: I did check and it appears the error has got to do with VS or Nuget package. Perhaps I have to try with VS 2015.